# Two errors to do with using a class

Tags: c++

I'm getting these two errors:

`sdlsetup.h(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'`

`sdlsetup.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

This is `sdlsetup.h` line 15:

```
CText* ctext;
```

The class is definitely set up properly and included in `sdlsetup.h`

Why is this?

EDIT: This is sdlsetup.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class SDLsetup
{
public:
    SDLsetup();
    ~SDLsetup();

    void Begin();
    void End();
    SDL_Renderer* GetRenderer();
    void EnterGameLoop();

    CText* ctext;


private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Event* mainEvent;

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
};
```

This is `Text.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class CText
{
public:
    CText();
    ~CText();

    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, std::string str);
    SDL_Texture* aGetMessage();
    SDL_Rect* aGetMessageRect();

private:
    TTF_Font* Sans;
    SDL_Color White;
    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage;
    SDL_Texture* Message;
    SDL_Rect Message_rect;
};
```

Comment: `CText` Do has been defined as a type before this line?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you're missing a semicolon somewhere at or above line 15. Start reading the source on line 15, and go backward to see if you missing a semicolon somewhere. If you don't find anything in that file, but you have `#include` preprocessor statements of your own header files, then look in those header files.

Comment: we need a compilable example which reproduces the problem (preferably without SDL dependencies)

Comment: Updated to have `sdlsetup.h`

Comment: Don't include `"stdafx.h"` in other header files, it's supposed to be included (first or all) in source files.

Comment: `sdlsetup.h` needs `#include <Text.h>`

Comment: Throws the same error.

Comment: `CText` It seems that to have failed to define CText(Text.h) is in need of information of the type of SDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the problem is a weird error message from the compiler, because it doesn't know what `CText` is.

You need to declare `CText` before you use it:

```
#pragma once

// Declare the CText class, so the compiler knows it exists
class CText;

class SDLsetup
{
public:
    ...

    CText* ctext;

    ...
};
```

Comment: @EthanWebster If you include the `Sdlsetup.h` header in any source-file where you don't include `text.h`? Of if you include `text.h` *after* `sdlsetup.h`? In those cases the compiler will not know about the name `CText` when you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add includes for Text.h in sdlsetup.h and also for the relevant SDL headers in both files.

Text.h needs to have `SDL.h`and `SDL_ttf.h`included and sdlsetup.h needs `SDL.h`and `Text.h`

Comment: The include for `Text.h` is present in `SDLsetup.cpp`

Comment: @EthanWebster The compiler won't be aware of what a CText is unless you either include the header in the file where you use it, or use a forward declaration as Joachim Pileborg suggested.

Comment: Even including `Text.h` in `SDLsetup.h` throws the exact same error.